# Creating a index on a date column that's already populated

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Is there any downside to creating a index on a already populated date field?

Will the new index perform the same as it would if it was created when the table was?

Would it be costly from a database perspective to add this?

Edit : the table has just under 10 million entries.

Comment: Is the table Partitioned ? If so, you might consider a LOCAL index ...(if not, you might consider partitioning a large table like that ;) )

Comment: Haha it's not parititoned. I need to do that as well for future records. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

There is no downside in creating an index at a later moment. The index will perform the same way like it would when it was created when the table was created.

You mentioned that the table has already 10 million rows. Therefore I would suggest that you create it during a 'calm' period. This because Oracle needs to lock the table. This cannot be done if there is a transaction that does an insert, update, or delete in the table.

Comment: Great thanks. When you say calm do you mean when there isn't a big load on the database or when there's no records been added?

Comment: No records being edited, removed, or added. I added this to my answer.

Comment: In case of Enterprise edition index can be created with `ONLINE` option which will allow DML operations during the creation.

Comment: is it possible that the index would be less fragmented if it's created later?

Comment: @JoeObbish  in my experience, initially it will.  But, as data is added/changed/delete, it will move to a more running state, which is not bad, and will still perform.  I don't subscribe to the idea of continually rebuilding indexes under normal conditions.